Flask OAuth2Session fetch_token returns "missing_token" error despite correct setup
I'm relatively new to Flask and am trying to develop a small application that uses OAuth for authentication. I'm using the requests_oauthlib library to handle the OAuth flow. My application successfully redirects users to the authorization page where they can log in. After logging in, it correctly receives an authorization code. However, I encounter an issue when trying to exchange this authorization code for an access token — I keep getting a "missing_token" error. Here's the relevant part of my code, along with the configuration:
The OAuth client is WP OAuth plugin:
WordPress Version : 6.5.4
PHP Version:    Ok - Version 8.3.8
Running CGI :   NO (OK)
Certificates Generated: Certificates Found | Regenerate Certificates
Public Key: 451 Bytes (März 18, 2024 12:58:22)
Private Key: 1704 Bytes (März 18, 2024 12:58:22)
Secure Server:  SECURE
Running Windows OS: No
Updates:    Disabled
Installation Key:   1718448895
OPEN SSL TEXT   OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
PHP cURL    version_number : 479488
age : 9
features : 364890013
ssl_version_number : 0
version : 7.81.0
host : x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ssl_version : OpenSSL/3.0.2
libz_version : 1.2.11
ares :
ares_num : 0
libidn : 2.3.2
iconv_ver_num : 0
libssh_version : libssh/0.9.6/openssl/zlib
brotli_ver_num : 16777225
brotli_version : 1.0.9

from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session, request
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)  # Used for securely signing the session

client_id = '*********************************'
client_secret = '*********************************'
authorization_base_url = 'https://*********************************/oauth/authorize'
token_url = 'https://*********************************/oauth/token'
redirect_uri = 'https://*********************************/callback'

@app.route("/")
def index():
    """Home view, displays login link"""
    return '<a href="/login">Login with WordPress</a>'

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    """Redirect to WordPress for login"""
    wordpress = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
    authorization_url, state = wordpress.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)

    # State is used to prevent CSRF, keep this for later.
    session['oauth_state'] = state
    return redirect(authorization_url)

@app.route("/callback")
def callback():
    wordpress = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_uri, state=session.get('oauth_state'))
    try:
        # Übergeben der erforderlichen Parameter, um den Access Token zu erhalten
        token = wordpress.fetch_token(
            token_url,
            authorization_response=request.url,
            client_secret=client_secret,
            # Automatisch setzen von grant_type="authorization_code"
            include_client_id=True
        )
        session['oauth_token'] = token
        return 'You are logged in with WordPress. <a href="/profile">View profile</a>'
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Authorization response URL: {request.url}")
        print(f"Error during token fetching: {e}")
        return f"Error: {e}"






@app.route("/profile")
def profile():
    """Fetching a protected resource using an OAuth token."""
    wordpress = OAuth2Session(client_id, token=session['oauth_token'])
    try:
        response = wordpress.get('https://*********************************/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me')
        return f'Profile (protected resource): {response.text}'
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error fetching profile: {e}"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=3000, debug=True, ssl_context=('cert.pem', 'key.pem'))



Error Message:
Error during token fetching: (missing_token) Missing access token parameter.
The authorization code is successfully retrieved.
The error occurs when trying to fetch the access token using fetch_token.
All URLs and client credentials are verified and correct.
Could anyone suggest why I might be encountering this issue and how to resolve it?
